# How to get data from a CSV file and place it in a list

Tags: java, csv

I want to read data from a CSV file in Java and then put this data into a list. The data in the CSV is put into rows which looks like:
Data, 32, 4.3
Month, May2, May 5

The code I have currently only prints the [32].

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("\\C:\\Users\\Book1.csv\\"));
scanner.useDelimiter(",");
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    myList.add(scanner.next());
    for (int i = 0; i <= myList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(myList.toString());
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: i'd grab line by line then split around the comma

Comment: why are you looping through myList inside the while loop? To be honest, you don't need to loop through a list at all to print it, just use `myList.toString()` outside the while loop, and it will print the entire contents of the list.

Comment: Thank you, the toString() worked outside of the while loop

Comment: In general I'd recommend using a CSV library, e.g. [commons-csv](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/), although it looks like your input is relatively simple. You probably want `myList[i].toString()` in your loop here though.

Comment: @val I think it's because it isn't properly being filled by your code.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this code can help you, maybe this code is different from yours, you use arrayList while I use regular array.

**Example of the data:**

- Farhan,3.84,4,72
- Rajab,2.98,4,72
- Agil,2.72,4,72
- Alpin,3.11,4,73
- Mono,3,6,118 K
- imel,3.97,7,132
- Rano,2.12,6,110
- Kukuh,4,1,22

**Placing data on each row in a csv file separated by commas into the array of each index**

```
    int tmp = 0;
    String read;
    Mahasiswa[] mhs = new Mahasiswa[100];

    BufferedWriter outs;
    BufferedReader ins;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        ins = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/file.csv"));
        tmp = 0;
        while ((read = ins.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] siswa = read.split(",");
            mhs[tmp] = new Mahasiswa();
            mhs[tmp].nama = siswa[0];
            mhs[tmp].ipk = Float.parseFloat(siswa[1]);
            mhs[tmp].sem = Integer.parseInt(siswa[2]);
            mhs[tmp].sks = Integer.parseInt(siswa[3]);
            tmp++;
            i++;
        }
        ins.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Terdapat Masalah: " + e);
    }
```

**Print the array data**

```
  tmp = 0; 
  while (tmp < i) {
  System.out.println(mhs[tmp].nama + "\t\t" + 
                      mhs[tmp].ipk + "\t\t" + 
                      mhs[tmp].sem + "\t\t" + 
                      mhs[tmp].sks);
                    tmp++;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Book1.csv"))) { 
    //here at your code there are backslashes at front and end of the path that was the
    //main reason you are not able to read csv file
            scanner.useDelimiter(",");
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                myList.add(scanner.next());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) { //remember index is always equal to "length - 1"
                System.out.println(myList);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

you also did not handle the `FileNotFoundException`

Hope this helps:)